# Get/set Jenkins global properties remotely

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to access and modify global properties in Jenkins from a remote machine (e.g. via any kind of web API)?
I browsed the Jenkins docs and looked at the source code. Also I couldn't find any plugin that fits my needs.

For clarification:
I'm talking about the 'Global properties' on page 'Manage Jenkins -> Configure System' (actually these are environment variables, as I understand it). - You can define and edit them only on the Jenkins page, as it seems.

Comment: What variables do you want to change?

Comment: The Jenkins UI calls them 'Global properties' (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System), but actually these are environment variables, as I understand it. You can define and edit them only on the Jenkins page, as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to set these environment variables remotely. But you can also set global environment variables in your Node configs as well. `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System-> Manage Nodes and Clouds` which has an API. So you may set the environment variables in each node.

```
https://JENKINS_URL/computer/(built-in)/api/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions and the first one worked for me, I didn't complete the code for the second one, but i did get the node variables

1. python run groovy script to add/update jenkins global variables.
   j is jenkins instance

   ```
   def update_env_variables(self, key, value):
   groovy_script = f'''
   import hudson.EnvVars;
   import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty;
   import hudson.slaves.NodeProperty;
   import hudson.slaves.NodePropertyDescriptor;
   import hudson.util.DescribableList;
   import jenkins.model.Jenkins;

   Jenkins instance = Jenkins.getInstance();

   DescribableList<NodeProperty<?>, NodePropertyDescriptor> globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties();
   List<EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty> envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class);

   EnvVars envVars = null;

   envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars();

   envVars.put('{key}', '{value}')
   instance.save()

   '''
   self.j.run_script(groovy_script)
   ```
2. If the name is the same, node system variables have higher priority than global variables, so you can add/update node variables instead of global variables